# Regex: Accepting space anywhere but at the beginning

Tags: c++, python, regex, qt, regex-negation

I'm working with Python bindings for Qt4.8 on OS X.

- I want to accept any digit and a few other chars AND white space.
- String can be empty or at any length.
- What I **don't want** is, for the **string to being or end with white space.**

My working example: `'[0-9pqw\+\-\*\#\(\)\.][0-9pqw\+\-\*\# \(\)\.]*'`

However, I don't want to repeat two blocks one containing space one does not. There should be a better way I guess, employing [^ ], but how?

Second question:

- If I want to limit strings total length, how would I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use negative [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the beginning and end of the pattern:

```
^(?![ ])[0-9pqw+*# ().-]*(?<![ ])$
```

Note that the brackets are not necessary but aid readability. Neither are any of your escapes (as long as you put the `-` at the end).

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do the trick! Can you explain the first bit '^(?![ ])' please if it's not too much of a trouble.

Comment: @Phil you should have a look at the tutorial I linked. it explains lookarounds better than I can. basically `(?!...)` tries to match `...` at the current position. If it can, the pattern fails. If it can't, the pattern continues - but the trick is, that this check does not actually advance the position of the engine's "cursor". That's why it's a "look"ahead. `(?<!...)` does the same to the left of the current position.

Comment: Thank you very much @m.buettner. I will read the link in full tonight as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do what you want?

```
import re 
re.match('^[^\W].*[^\W]$', '  aaa ')
```

(Where the last arg is your test string).

If you want to ensure the length is less than a certain amount use curly braces. One character is already spent testing the first and last chars of the test string with the inclusion of the `[^\W]` notation. So in this example, there is a match when there are no spaces at either side and when the test string is no longer than 4 characters.

```
re.match('^[^\W].{1,2}[^\W]$', 'aaaa')
```